# My score and functions dont work

Tags: python

```
a=True
import random                                   #Here i imported a random module
score=0                                 #I made a variable called score and set it to 0
while a == True:                          #Opens a loop called a
    name=input("What is your name? ")       #I asked the user their name here if name == (""):
    if name.isdigit() or name == (""):       #If the user enters a number or nothing something will happen
        print("Incorrect Name")          #This is the message that appears when the the name is a number or is nothing is incorrect
    else:
        a=False                              #Here i closed a loop
        print("Welcome To my quiz " +str(name))            #This is the welcoming message


def addition():                            #Here i define a function called addition
    score=0                              #Here the score shows score
    first_number_a=random.randint(1,10)         #The program gets a random number
    second_number_a=random.randint(1,10)                  #The program gets another random number
    question1=int(input("What is " +str(first_number_a)+ "+" +str(second_number_a)+ " "))                #Here the program asks the user a question
    total_a=(first_number_a+second_number_a)                         #The answer to the question above
    if question1 == total_a:                  #If answer is equal to the new variable c which is the answer to the question
        print("Correct!")               #This tells the user they got it correct
        score=score+1                   #This adds a point to the score
    else:                               # if answer is not the variable
        print("Incorrect!")             #Here the program will print that the user is incorrect
        print(total_a)                        #Here the program prints the correct answer if they got the question wrong
        return score         #This keeps the score safe


def multiplication():
    score=0
    first_number_m=random.randint(1,10)
    second_number_m=random.randint(1,10)
    question2=int(input("What is " +str(first_number_m)+ "*" +str(second_number_m)+ " "))
    total_m=(first_number_m*second_number_m)
    if question2 == total_m:
        print("Correct!")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        print(total_m)
        return score

def subtraction():
    score=0
    first_number_s=random.randint(1,10)
    second_number_s=random.randint(1,10)
    question3=int(input("What is " +str(first_number_s)+ "-" +str(second_number_s)+ " "))
    total_s=(first_number_s-second_number_s)
    if question3 == total_s:
        print("Correct!")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        print(total_s)
    return score

qw=["a" , "b" , "c"]              #List Of Letters that will be randomly selected to then start a function
for i in range(0,10):            #Thsi willrepeat the process listed below however many times in this example 10 times
    random_Letter=random.choice(qw)     #Selets a random letter   
    if random_Letter == "a":                #If the random letter is a
       score += addition()              #It will use the function addition
    if random_Letter == "b":
       score += multiplication()
    if random_Letter == "c":
       score += subtraction()
print("your score is " +str(score)+ " Out of 10")     #Tells the user their final score
```

The main problems with the last part the program upon running it shows incorrect operand type but this only happens with addition and multiplication not with subtraction which is confusing every time the program asks a addition of multiplication and I answer it correct or incorrect it shows up the following message unsupported operand type(s) for +=: `int` and `NoneType`.

Comment: Please get rid of this `while a == True:`. Just use `while True:` and `break` out of the loop when the condition is met.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't indent correctly the `return score` in your function. Currently, it returns score only in the else part:

```
if question2 == total_m:
    print("Correct!")
    score=score+1
else:
    print("Incorrect!")
    print(total_m)
    return score
```

So if you print correct, the function returns "nothing", that is `NoneType`.
Change to

```
if question2 == total_m:
    print("Correct!")
    score=score+1
else:
    print("Incorrect!")
    print(total_m)
return score
```